# how to show a portion of image like on 9gag.com

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

how to show only a portion( in this case is to hide the watermark) of image like on 9gag.com, 
I tried to use clip in css, but it requires image to be position absolute, which is a no no for me.

is there other way to do this in css? js is ok too.

thank you.

////////////////////////////////////////////////
here is the solution to my problem, took me a while to figure out i can use a margin attribute, silly me

```
img {margin:0 auto -33px;}
```

Comment: Why can't you use `position:absolute`? If you wrap it in a `position:relative` container it will be absolute to that container.

Comment: I did what you recommended, it breaks the page.

Comment: Please post your solution as an actual answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use the CSS overflow property. You can do `overflow: hidden;` to clip out entities beyond the width and height of a container.

You can learn more at W3schools: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp
They even have an example for you to try out.

Comment: my website is similar to 9gag, contains alot of image post, with more added daily,so the containers will all have different height and width, so this will not work in my case

Comment: Well, you could write a script that detects individual images' heights and widths, right? And then calculate how much to cover up with `overflow:hidden` right?

Comment: well, I want to move up exactly 100px from the bottom for every images. I am trying to avoid using additional script, because it will add stress to the server, mine only has about 60 mb of free memory

Comment: How about a script in javascript? That's client side and doesn't tax the server.

Answer (score 0):

You only need CSS for this.  You will use the same technique used on many sites to reduce HTTP resource requests (called sprites).

You create a div, setting the image as the background image.  You then set the desired height and width of the div.  If you don't want to just snip the lower right hand side, you can adjust the background-position CSS attribute.

See [here](http://www.guistuff.com/css/css_imagetech1.html) for an example.

Comment: yea, I know how to use sprites, but my website is similar to 9gag, contains alot of image post, with more added daily, I can't use  sprites in this case.

Comment: I'm not saying use sprites.  I'm saying that you will use the same technique of covering a portion of an image.